# How to pre select multiple months in a calendar control - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am making tenant management system for one of my client and in that application there is one requirement where I have to highlight those months and NOT DATES which is not paid by tenants. I tried hard looking for the solution but couldnt find. Below is the calendar control which I am using.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt26L.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the existing `DatePicker` control. It is designed to select a single date only. You will need to build your own control for this, or find an existing third-party control.